# An unhandled exception occurred during the execution

Tags: c#, exception

I have handling the exception in my code as below, but still get error :

```
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
```

And here is the error :

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Its not a good practice to wrap an exception like that. The new exception that you are throwing does not have the original stack trace information. Plus there is no point in catching an exception that you will just throw again.

Comment: Agreed with Darkoleptiko. Just remove the 'throw' line and replace it with something that useful like a notification i.e a message box: MessageBox.Show("Error: "+e.ToString())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are handling your exception in this way (only retrowing it) than don't catch exeptions on this level. Catch Exceptions in the method that's calling this function (Or where you want to handle your exception) and do your handling/showing the message overthere.

You probably don't have another try/catch block in the calling method which is causing the unhandled exception.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like you are accessing a object that has been released/ or a null object.

Answer (score 0):

IN the Catch block instead you use the following code to display an exception u r again throwing the Exception, remove it  and try again. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think MessageBox will be available in a Web project.

Comment: this code is located in my custom membership provider, in asp.net application.

Answer (score 0):

You still get an error because you are throwing a new exception in the catch block.

Comment: I used this code in "GetUserNameByEmail" method of my custom membership provider.

Answer (score 0):

From a catch block you are throwing a new excpetion which is creating a problem try to remove throw new exception or add a new parent try catch block